Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Which branch of psychology deals with decision making under stress?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)  
What is the standard error of measurement for teacher made multiple choice tests?
Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)  
How to compute Chi-square value and degrees of freedom in Excel?
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Can we draw conclusions about content of thoughts from neural firing patterns?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Term for incentives working without conscious awareness
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Are cortisol measures more reliable than self-reported fear measures for looking at difference scores?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Devices that detect when someone is falling asleep
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Do children follow parents' phobias genetically or by learning?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Training for the corpus callosum?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Is learning facts via audio while sleeping possible?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)  

